# Ajax returning whole HTML page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is a common question around the internets but no solution is working for me. It errors out whenever I add the dataType:'json'. I have also tried putting the data in this form "date=2014-12-15" and leaving out the datatype. I tried formatting my JSON in numerous ways. What I want to do is send the date to the PHP page and then return the $datalisting string back to the ajax page. But seems like whatever I do, whenever I get success, it returns all the HTML from the page with the ajax. ..quite stumped here.

```
$(".upcoming-event-dates").click(function(e){
  var date = {"date": "2014-12-15"};
  e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: date,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     url: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/date-process.php',
     cache: false,
     success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
         },
     error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
     alert("cheese helmet");
     },
     timeout : 15000
     });
});
```

and the php code

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );
$start = $_POST['date'];

$dataListing = "do_shortcode('[events_list_grouped mode='weekly' scope='".$start.",".$start."'                limit='5']</div>

                      <div class='home-calendar-right'>
                      <div class='home-calendar-time-title'>#_EVENTTIMES #_EVENTLINK[/events_list_grouped]')";
                      echo $datedListing;
```

Comment: That is by design - all data from the page is returned. If you want to return JSON you have to create JSON in your PHP file. Your dataType here should be HTML.

Comment: The contents of `$datedListing` sure don't look like JSON to me...

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're working in WordPress? I don't think you're supposed to use wp_load in an AJAX page in WP. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: What do you mean it's returning all the HTML?  Are you talking about things like `<div class='home-calendar-right'>` or are you talking like `<html><head></head><body>...</body></html>`?

Comment: Elaborate? How so? You're generating HTML in the requested page, so your return will be HTML.

Comment: Get rid of the `contentType` option. `$.ajax` sends `x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `application/json`.

Comment: Ok, I was confused then, I thought the dataType had to be set for the data I was passing. So if I want to return a string, I can just leave datatype to default of text...but when I do that, I get the whole HTML page returned.

Comment: Even without content type or datatype, I get the whole HTML page returned. when i do data: 'date=2014-12-15', that doesn't work either.

Comment: @SeanAnderson: The result is going to be whatever that page emits.  If that page is emitting a "whole page" then that's exactly what's going to be returned.  Is there more server-side code which is producing more HTML markup?  Maybe in that included PHP file, for example?

Comment: Why are you using POST? Why are you rendering HTML in PHP code if you want to work with JSON?

Comment: @SeanAnderson: `"when i do data: 'date=2014-12-15', that doesn't work either"` - Define "doesn't work."  Why are you changing how the data is sent to the server?  Is *that* not working as expected?  Is the server-side code not getting the `date` value?  It's not really clear what you're asking here.

Comment: AHA! ok! That required page was the problem. Shoot...should have thought about that. That code was passed on to me from elsewhere so I left it. Think I am good now.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick replies.

Comment: In case someone stumbles upon this..the problem was not in fact the require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' ); , it was because I had the .php file in the template directory of Wordpress and was pulling the HTML from the Header and Footer files. #noobproblems